# Set activated item in ListView programmatically

Tags: android, listview

I have a simple `ListView` with some items that have `setChoiceMode` set to `ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE`, which means when I touch an item, it is highlighted. This way the user can see what menu choice (the `ListView` is a menu) was chosen:

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

However, I want to change that selection from code (not by touching). I tried this:

```
listView.setSelection(0);
```

but it seems to have no effect. Probably because selection and activation are different concepts. There is no `setActivated(int)` method available.

Comment: try `.setItemChecked(position, true);`

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan that's it. Your comment should be an answer :).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you can select item with following code:

```
listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
```

Comment: I tried this in onCreate() method have initializing the list and setting the adapter.  Is there another place I should I call this ? .. Thanks

Comment: @gnB you must use this code after setting adapter to your listView

Answer (score 2):

Using this method worked for me

```
listView.performItemClick(listView, position, listView.getItemIdAtPosition(position));
```

Comment: Hi I tried this, but the value for the last param call returns 0.  I tried it here: long itemId = myListView.getItemIdAtPosition(0);  , and I get an exception from that.  I call this in the onCreate() method .. is there another place I should call it?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says `If in touch mode, the item will not be selected but it will still be positioned appropriately`.

So, you need to use `ListView.setItemChecked(int position, boolean checked)` method as `listView.setItemChecked(position, true)` to set the position as selected

Comment: where is that touchmode?